# Having trouble submitting question with android app

Tags: support, status-completed, android-app

When I post a question with the app I get a nice preview with my tags etc visible, but when I press submit, it thinks about something for a while then goes back to the question edit activity. No question submitted, no errors given.

Screnshots:
Editing my question :

[image: question editing]

After pressing submit, note random title (didn't see that first time round):

[image: post submit random title]

After confirming preview, submitting again:

[image: post submit again]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that, caught that bug this morning. It'll be fixed in the build from tonight.

Comment: You do realise you are significantly responsible for making my phone "ding" at me to remind me of my Stack Addiction, right? (which is to say, I'm loving it!)

Comment: @kasra-rahjerdi I am using version 1.0.43 on Android 4.3 and I have this problem. Is the correct protocol to comment here, or ask a new question?

Comment: @I.T.Navigate Please ask a new question with the android-app tag and include any error messages